# ASCII encoding is not working as expected when getting the hex value of a character in C#

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a text file with different characters and want to convert each character in HEX values. I am using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` and then converting each byte to hex.

But the result is not correct each time. Some characters does not show their correct hex values and expected. For example the charcter `'î'` should return the expected hex value `8C` according to the provided document, but the code below returns `3F`.

The code which is used is as following:

```
string myBytes = String.Empty;
string dp = "î";                 
byte[] bdp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dp);
foreach (byte b in bdp)
{
myBytes += b.ToString("x") + " ";
}
```

Comment: In your example code is that an 'i'?

Comment: Looks like an i circumflex, which is not an ASCII character

Comment: There is no "î" character in ASCII. ASCII only got 127 characters (0-127). Everything else is translated to '?' (0x3f). You probably want another encoding

Comment: The letter î is not a standard ASCII character. You should check which exact encoding needs to be used (if you want to use 7 bit ASCII). Otherwise, if it's a custom mapping of chars to values, you need to post the exact specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this way

```
string myBytes = String.Empty;
string dp = "î";                 

//byte[] bdp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dp);
byte[] bdp = Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetBytes(dp);  //  <----- NOTE 437

foreach (byte b in bdp)
{
    myBytes += b.ToString("x") + " ";
}
```

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

### Edit:

The ASCII is defined from 0-127 only. The c# ASCII Encoding can handle only this many characters. the `î` character is not in those. You are probably talking about *ASCII* as it was in good old MS-DOS and older IBM-PC. those machines understood a slightly different set of characters. the basics (31-127) were same as modern day ASCII and even Unicode. but other were different. That dialect of characters is called CODE-PAGE-437.

Comment: +1. How did you figure out it was 437? I came across http://www.ascii-code.com and it states that 'î' belongs to extended ASCII characters, mainly ISO Latin-1 :|

Comment: @CodeART, i too first landed at ascii-code.com but found `î` to be at `EE`. it was expected to be at `8C`. the odd thing i noticed was that the *extended* set did not contain the Box-Drawing characters. as a child i always liked the old simple way of drawing boxes on MSDOS with simple characters. so i realized that ascii has got to have multiple flavors. the first google search on *msdos ascii* gave me code-page 437. it had the `î` at `8C`. :)